# mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ms.example.model.Address.address in com.ms.example.model.Customer.addresses

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Firstly, I have gone through multiple links to fix the problem, but still couldn't.
I have 3 classes: Customer, Address and Subscription
A customer can have multiple addresses.
A customer can have multiple subscriptions.

```
package com.ms.example.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private String customerId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private Long phoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private LocalDate creationDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")
    private List<Address> addresses;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subscription")
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions;


}
package com.ms.example.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "address_id")
    private String addressId;
    @Column(name = "address1")
    private String address1;
    @Column(name = "address2")
    private String address2;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
    @Column(name = "last_update_date")
    private LocalDate lastUpdateDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

}

package com.ms.example.model;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.time.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscription")
public class Subscription {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "subscription_id")
    private String subscriptionId;
    @Column(name = "subscription_on_date")
    private LocalDate subscriptionOnDate;
    @Column(name = "subscription_off_date")
    private LocalDate subscriptionOffDate;
    @Column(name = "balance_pending")
    private BigDecimal balancePending;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

While running I am getting this error:

Can someone please help what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.ms.example.customerdataservice.model.Address.address in com.ms.example.customerdataservice.model.Customer.addresses
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:875) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:826) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1653) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1629) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.12.Final.jar:5.6.12.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
... 21 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "address")` must be `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")`. You referenced the property in the Fk class

Comment: Guide on how to map One To Many (Vlad Mihalcea is a Java Champion and one of the top Hibernate ORM committers): https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/